# How to estimate derivative of state in state-space model?

Tags: state-space

I would like to know what would be the best way to estimate a derivative of state of state-space model. I one would like to estimate one of the state, then the Kalman filter should work just fine. However, if the state of interest is not one of the state, what could be done?

Let's say there is a A,B,C,D state-space model of a falling object with some vertical forces, F1, F2 and positional sensor y. Say F1 is known input and F2 is an unknown but significant disturbance. I guess the most common state-space model would be;

$$\begin{matrix} \dot{x} \\ \ddot{x} \end{matrix} = \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} *\begin{matrix} x \\ \dot{x} \end{matrix} + \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1/m & 1/m & -1 \end{matrix}*\begin{matrix} F1 \\ F2 \\ g\end{matrix}$$

$$\begin{matrix} y \end{matrix} = \begin{matrix} 1& 0 \end{matrix}*\begin{matrix} x \\\dot{x} \end{matrix} + O *\begin{matrix} F1 \\ F2 \\ g\end{matrix}$$.

In this example, how could one estimate $$ \ddot{x} $$?

Should one expand the state vector so that the Kalman filter could be utilized? If so, what would be the A, B, C, D matrix? How about estimate first derivative with the Kalman filter and putting it thru a differentiator? If not, how could it be done?

- Considering the other purpose of the controller not mention in the question, expanding the state vector is desirable, if possible.